# backbone view with dynamic id

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I just realized I was misunderstanding the `el` attribute of a `Backbone.View`. Basically my views require dynamic `id` attributes based on its model's attribute. I thought I had this working fine because I simply specified it in my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item_template">
  <li class="item" id="{{identifier}}">
    <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
  </li>
</script>
```

However, I realized that what Backbone was actually doing was putting this compiled template into another element, `div` by default. I learned more about this by reading the documentation, but I'm still confused on how to create a dynamic `id`.

Preferably, I would love to find a way to make it such that the stuff in the above template serves as my `el`, since it already has everything I want, but I don't know if that is possible. So I'm wondering if, quite simply, there is a way to specify a dynamic `id` attribute.

I tried setting it within the `initialize` method, `this.id = this.model.get('attr')` but it didn't seem to have any effect, possibly because by this time it is already too late.

What I'm currently doing is just using jQuery to add the `id` in during `render()`:

```
this.el.attr(id: this.model.get('identifier'));
```

it works, but of course, I'm simply asking if there is a preferred way to do it through Backbone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is a standard way to do this in Backbone. You can pass `id` to the View constructor. You can also refactor your template so that Backbone creates the parent `<li>` element for you. Try this simpler template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item_template">
  <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
</script>
```

And add these to your view:

```
myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "item",
  tagName: "li"
})
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
var view = new YourView({
  model: mymodel,
  id: mymodel.get('identifier') // or whatever
})
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again maxl0rd (helped me on the other question :D). This actually seems like it should work :D I'll try it and come back to mark as correct :)

Comment: for those that don't know, tagName defaults to div if not specified.
i'll see a good number of templates that have a container [form, div, etc... with an id] and that really should be part of the view and not the template often. as shown in maxl0rd's answer

Answer (score 5):

There is one more approach. I found it more convenient than passing `id` every time you create an instance of your view.

Template:

```
 <script type="text/template" id="item_template">
      <span class="name">{{name}}</span>
 </script>
```

View:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    attributes: function(){
       return { 
           id: this.model.get('identifier'),
           class: 'item'//optionally, you could define it statically like before
       }
    }
})
```

Comment: up-vote this answer, because it has general solution defined in 'constructor'

Answer (score 1):

When you create your view, pass in a selector that will let the view find your existing pre-rendered DOM element:

```
var id = "1234";
var view = YourView({el: '#'+id});
```

Comment: The element is not pre-rendered, and it is not in the DOM as far as I know. It's just there as a template, within a script tag.