# Backbone list item view tag controlled by template

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js, idioms

I have a ListView with a bunch of ListItemViews in them, using templates in the html file. I found out fairly quickly that Backbone expects the view to control the element involved so that it can delegate events, etc. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8218085/410882) shows a standard way of customizing common things in the outer tag like id.

I just feel a bit weird about not having the outer tag in my template. If I want to have assign a class or even change the kind of element, it seems more intuitive to be in the template IMO. In most cases I can assign the view to an existing element, but for item views of a collection it has to create new views and elements from scratch.

I can use setElement to assign a string to el and delegate the events. However when re-rendering the control later on (like after an edit), this breaks the connection to the DOM. My solution was to wrap setSelement, using jQuery's replaceWith to switch the old element with the new one:

```
window.Backbone.View.prototype.replaceElement = (element) ->
  old = @$el
  @setElement element, true
  old.replaceWith @$el
```

Then I can use it in the view:

```
render: () ->
  @replaceElement @template @model.toJSON()
  return @
```

With template:

```
<script id="actionTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li id="{{id}}"><input type="checkbox" />{{name}}</li>
</script>
```

Can anyone see any pitfalls with this? My main concerns are that it is probably slower than just swapping the html from an existing tag and more importantly that it is just not idiomatic enough? Perhaps I'm being silly to fight the framework when it really wants me to keep just the content of the tag in the template?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you the `@el` of your view is still the original one that you have replaced with the new one. So all event listeners of your still listen to this old element. So you have to write something like this:

```
window.Backbone.View.prototype.replaceElement = (element) ->
  old = @$el
  @setElement element, true
  old.replaceWith @$el
  @setElement element
```

Beside this, if you just wanna create a list of items its not a good idea to create a new view instance for every item. One view that has an `ul` element and a template that iterates over your list should be enough.

```
<script id="actionTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
    {{each items}}
        <li id="{{id}}"><input type="checkbox" />{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused on why the second setElement is required? Looking at the [Backbone source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-155), setElement(newEl, true) will remove all events from the old element using undelegateEvents and delegate onto newEl. And you can set events onto an element that isn't in the DOM yet, so I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: For the second point, each row can delete or edit in place. E.g. on clicking delete, it destroys the model. The view listens on this and removes itself without re-rendering the whole list. I also have a list view for things like re-sorting.

I could e.g. give delete links unique id, listen at list level and re-render whole list but not sure it's worth it?